# Metamask API support for interacting with Ethereum contracts

Tags: web3js, erc-20, metamask, erc-721, web3-providers

Metamask stopped using web3. Their own API has no methods for interacting with ERC20, ERC721 contracts. How do I accomplish simple task of reading token balance for a wallet on an ERC721 contract?

https://metamask.github.io/api-playground/api-documentation

Comment: `Metamask stopped using web3.`  This is not true.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `eth_call` on [Metamask API Docs](https://metamask.github.io/api-playground/api-documentation/#eth_call).

Here is an example query for retrieving ERC20 balance:

```
{
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"method": "eth_call",
"params": [
    {
        "data": "0x70a0823100000000000000000000000028c6c06298d514db089934071355e5743bf21d60",
        "to": "0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7"
    },
    "latest"
],
"id": 0
}
```

`to` is the contract address (in this case - USDT)

`data` consists of:

1. the first 4 bytes of `keccak256(balanceOf(address))` (function hash)
2. the wallet address that you want to retrieve balance for (in this example - `0x28c6c06298d514db089934071355e5743bf21d60`).

The same should work for NFTs since ERC721 balanceOf matches ERC20 specs.